# How to pass multidimensional functions as argument in f2py?

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I want to call a fortran subroutine from python, where I want to pass a function to the subroutine that has an array as input and output. As a first step I am trying this on a quite simple example, but I cannot even seem to get this to work. F2py seems to have a problem when it gets to this callback function. Here is my

```pascal
subroutine foo(B, A, f, n)
  integer, parameter :: dp=kind(0.d0)

  integer,  intent(in)  :: n
  real(dp), intent(out) :: B(n)
  real(dp), intent(in)  :: A(n)

  external f

  interface
      function f(arr) result(res)
        integer, parameter :: dp=kind(0.d0)

        real(dp), intent(in) :: arr(:)
        real(dp)             :: res(size(arr))
      end function 
  end interface

  B = f(A)
end subroutine
```

The python callback function could look something like this:

```py
def f(x):
    return np.array([2*x[1], x[0]*x[1]])
```

Currently I am getting the error `capi_return is NULL`  `Call-back cb_func_in_foo__user__routines failed.`

Edit: Found out that using a subroutine for the callback f instead of a function fixed the problem.

Comment: unfortunately, i dont have the time right now but i think this [documentation's section](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/f2py/python-usage.html#call-back-arguments) might be of help.

Comment: I found out that the problem was using a function rather than a subroutine for the callback function. I don't know why this works and not what I tried, since it seemed to work when running in just Fortran. Thanks anyway!